# Handling a long equation in Maple (probably a silly question)

Tags: symbolic-math, maple

I'm sorry if this is a silly and simple question. I'm a Maple noob, and the more I searched about this the less I found about it.

I have a system of equations that I solved. I assigned one of the solutions to another variable (as in xsol := sol['x'][1])

First, the expression is very long. I cannot get to print it or in any way record it anywhere to work with it. Not sure how I can export it in a standard form to use it in another software.

Second, I want to solve this equation (as is xsol=0) for one of the variables that is in that equation. However, according to the variables panel in maple, xsol stores as a Name/Symbol (not a formula or even a set). Yet, type (xsol, 'name'), or even better type (xsol) returns false!
When I print it, it shows as an expression in between two parantheses, which I don't know what it means in this case.

Because of that, the solve command doesn't work on it. rhs command also doesn't work on it because of the way it is defined. I'm totally lost and I'd really appreciate it if someone can help me with it.

Thank you!

tried unapply, value, eval, and none changed it. It couldn't be indexed too. The same variable is stored. (xol1 := xsol[1]  stores the same xsol in xsol1)

Comment: It would help others understand what's going on if you say what are the equations you are trying to solve, or at least a simplified version of them. (Given that the problem you're having seems to be something about evaluation and assignment, maybe a simple version is enough.)